# How to Execute SSIS package from local,but files like (.csv, .xls...) are on VM

Tags: ssis, ssis-connection-manager

How to execute SSIS package from local machine, where there are different source files are on VM machine which are source file for this packages,
how SSIS packages can connect to the VM Machine for the source files and can execute the packages.

Answer (score 1):

A VM is just another computer so the same "tricks" apply. Create a file share on the virtual machine, ensure the permissions are set appropriately, ensure the firewall allows access, etc.

Modify your SSIS package to look for files on `\\vm1\share\datafolder`